# Is the Nunchuk required for Star Wars: The Force Unleashed?

Tags: nintendo-wii, star-wars-the-force-unleashed

Is there any way for two players to play Star Wars: The Force Unleashed without a Nunchuk (or only using one Nunchuk)?

Comment: Wii games usually have a picture on the back of the box showing what controller combinations are supported/required. Unfortunately I can't find an image of the back of the box :(

Answer (score 5):

#### The nunchuck is required.

Pretty sure that you can't play without a nunchuck (or share one between two players), since your Force powers are only accessed with the nunchuck.

Answer (score 1):

No, you definitely need a Nunchuk for every player. A lot of games have this limitation.